# Conflict between gems "aws" and "aws-s3"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rubygems, amazon-web-services

in a Rails 2.3.11 project I had only the gem "aws-s3" (v: 0.6.2) working correctly, but since I added (for a dependency) the gem "aws" (v: 2.5.6) I noticed some warnings during mongrel startup like:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/aws-2.5.6/lib/ses/../awsbase/utils.rb:105: warning: already initialized constant HEX
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/aws-2.5.6/lib/ses/../awsbase/utils.rb:107: warning: already initialized constant TO_REMEMBER
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/aws-2.5.6/lib/ses/../awsbase/utils.rb:108: warning: already initialized constant ASCII
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/aws-2.5.6/lib/ses/../awsbase/errors.rb:128: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_CLOSE_ON_4XX_PROBABILITY
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/aws-2.5.6/lib/ses/../awsbase/parsers.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_XML_LIBRARY
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/aws-2.5.6/lib/ses/../awsbase/awsbase.rb:66: warning: already initialized constant AMAZON_PROBLEMS
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/aws-2.5.6/lib/ses/../awsbase/awsbase.rb:86: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_SIGNATURE_VERSION
/Users/me/Documents/development/prj/myprj/config/initializers/omniauth.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant VERIFY_PEER
```

But the application is working well. Do you think that there can be some pitfalls? Any advice on how to solve this warnings?

Thank you very much!

Comment: you should compare the values of the constants in both gems. If there is one difference, it could be hazardous.

Comment: It does not seem an incompatibility issue between those two gems to me.
Maybe more an issue on aws gem, look at this: https://github.com/appoxy/aws/issues/84

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any incompatibilities between these gems so you should be alright. Also, do you see those warnings when running in production (ie: cache_classes = true)?  It may just be due to the reloading in Rails development.

Comment: Hi Travis, reading the comment of Andrea Salicetti the issue seems to be inside the aws gem...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think putting both is the better way
This aws-s3 gem is part of the AWS SDK for Ruby.
So firs remove both from your project 
And make clean project with only one dependency aws-sdk for s3 modules use internal s3 function from aws-sdk